# Prefetching a larger image for hover div Page Speed issue

Tags: html, image, pagespeed

I currently have a page with about 20 or images with source data pulled from a database.

I display them at width of 100px and I have a hover function that appends an element with the full size image with a width of 250px.

I decided to use the full size version for the original image and just scale it down to 100px instead of using a thumbnail version.  My thinking on this was that on this page it is very likely that the user will hover over most of the images so the page would end up having to load the full size version for most of the images anyway so why make them download the thumbnail AND full size version for each element.  Also scaling from 250px to 100px didn't seem to display much if any distortion in the smaller element.

Now I am running my page through Google page speed analyzer and it really does not like me using larger than necessary images for the smaller elements.  Of course it is ignoring the fact that those larger images are being used for the dynamically created popups.

In order to make my page play nice with Google's page speed tester I am giving in and using thumbnails for the smaller elements but I also want to prefetch the larger image to avoid an annoying delay when the user hovers over the element.  This means I am essentially loading 2 versions of the same image just to make Google speed test not yell at me.

This seems ridiculous to me so I wanted to ask if this is really the best way to do this or is there another way to make my page play nice with Google speed test.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you're doing, there's no need to be a slave to the PageSpeed score.

Loading two copies of the images could make actual page speed slower. However, it depends on what you are trying to optimize for. Loading thumbnails first and then large versions could be better if you want time to full render to be fast (so the users can see the page) and then load the big images in the background to add interactivity later.

Or is it better to have fast time to interactivity, and time to full render doesn't matter that much. Then maybe having one copy of each image is better.